# Random variable X has Bernoulli distribution with parameters $(10,\frac{1}{4})$. What's the probability of $p(X\geq 10)$

Tags: probability

Random variable X has Bernoulli distribution with parameters $(10,\frac{1}{4})$. What's the probability of $p(X\geq 10)$

Am I supposed to use this formula?

$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k}$ for $k=0,1,..,n$

$P(X=10)=0$, I can't calculate values greater then $11$ since $n=10$

How can I calculate the probability there, is the answer just $0$?

@edit

$E(X)=np=10 \cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{10}{4}$

$D^{X}X=npq=\frac{30}{16}$

$DX=\sqrt{\frac{30}{16}}$

$P(X<10)=1-P(X\leq 9)=1-F(x=9)=?$

$U=\frac{9-E(X)}{D(X)}=\frac{26}{\sqrt{30}} P(X\geq 10)=$

$1-F(x=9)=1-F(U=\frac{26}{\sqrt{30}}=1-F(U=~4.747)$

Answer (score 3):

the support of your rv is

$k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$

any other value of k has probability zero.

So

$$\mathbb{P}[X \geq10]=\mathbb{P}[X=10]=\binom{10}{10}p^{10}(1-p)^0=p^{10}=\frac{1}{4^{10}}$$

Comment: Could you check edit in main post? My friend was doing same task and I understand nothing of it, your answer is nice and simple so I hope this edit doesn't make much sense. :P

Comment: @Gorosso : $P[X<10]=1-P[X=10]=1-\frac{1}{4^{10}}$